# Pip Installing in my own package (in editable mode) does not expose the package to my system

Tags: python-3.x, pip, setuptools

**Description of the problem**

When installing my `coolcustom` package via `py -3.11 -m pip install -e .` the package cannot be imported from elsewhere.

**Minimal example of reproducing my problem**

My project structure looks like this

```
Documents/
├─ testing_package/
│  ├─ coolcustom/
│  │  ├─ __init__.py
│  │  ├─ setup.py
│  │  ├─ main.py
```

`setup.py` looks like this

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='coolcustom',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
)
```

After I install the package using

```
C:\...\Documents\testing_package\coolcustom>py -3.11 -m pip install -e .
Obtaining file:///C:/Users/viktor/Documents/testing_package/coolcustom
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Checking if build backend supports build_editable ... done
  Getting requirements to build editable ... done
  Preparing editable metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: coolcustom
  Building editable for coolcustom (pyproject.toml) ... done
  Created wheel for coolcustom: filename=coolcustom-0.1-0.editable-py3-none-any.whl size=2425 sha256=1fcbdb8196af21eee8da2dd58bec327bb0de614e89d1e36af51bf3ef4a77d7ad
  Stored in directory: C:...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-oucj9xsh\wheels\7a\b2\30\0f92e762acafbb9145d2d426806835dd76cbee08ff561f565b
Successfully built coolcustom
Installing collected packages: coolcustom
Successfully installed coolcustom-0.1
```

No errors seem to popup. I even verify the installation with

```
py -3.11 -m pip list
Package                  Version      Editable project location
------------------------ ------------ ----------------------------------------------------
..other packages here
coolcustom               0.1          C:...\Documents\testing_package\coolcustom
```

However when I `cd` out of the project and try to import the `coolcustom` package it fails

```
cd ../..
C:...\Documents>py -3.11 -c "import coolcustom"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'coolcustom'
```

**What I have tried so far**

1. Installing the package in non-editable (normal) mode after uninstalling the editable version and it still did not work
2. I could not find .egg-link file neither in `\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages` nor in `\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages`
3. However I have found `coolcustom-0.1.dist-info` folder, `__editable___coolcustom_0_1_finder.py`, and `__editable__.coolcustom-0.1.pth` inside the `\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages` meaning that the setup did do something.

I am very new to using setuptools, so maybe there is an obvious error I am doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot that setup.py is supposed to be in the outside folder... sorry